# "gradle publish" wrongly reporting up-to-date

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to build [Apache S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/) and publish it to our Nexus repository. `gradle publishToMavenLocal` worked, so I added

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "admin"
                password "admin123"
            }
            url "http://127.0.0.1:9081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

to `build.gradle` after `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`. This worked for other projects on the same machine. However, now I get

```
aromanov@ws:~/etc/apache-s4-0.6.0$ gradle clean publish
Build file '/home/aromanov/etc/apache-s4-0.6.0/subprojects/s4-benchmarks/s4-benchmarks.gradle': line 42
The RepositoryHandler.mavenRepo() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the maven() method instead.
Runs Apache RAT. Exclusions are defined in .rat-excludes fileUNDEFINED
:clean
:s4-base:clean
:s4-benchmarks:clean
:s4-comm:clean
:s4-core:clean
:s4-tools:clean
:test-apps:clean
:test-apps:consumer-app:clean
:test-apps:producer-app:clean
:test-apps:simple-deployable-app-1:clean
:s4-base:publish UP-TO-DATE
:s4-benchmarks:publish UP-TO-DATE
:s4-comm:publish UP-TO-DATE
:s4-core:publish UP-TO-DATE
:s4-tools:publish UP-TO-DATE
:test-apps:publish UP-TO-DATE
:test-apps:consumer-app:publish UP-TO-DATE
:test-apps:producer-app:publish UP-TO-DATE
:test-apps:simple-deployable-app-1:publish UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.468 secs
```

Using `gradle -i` I get

```
Selected primary task 'publish'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':s4-base:publish', task ':s4-benchmarks:publish', task ':s4-comm:publish', task ':s4-core:publish', task ':s4-tools:publish', task ':test-apps:publish', task ':test-apps:consumer-app:publish', task ':test-apps:producer-app:publish', task ':test-apps:simple-deployable-app-1:publish']
:s4-base:publish (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:s4-base:publish
Skipping task ':s4-base:publish' as it has no actions.
:s4-base:publish UP-TO-DATE
:s4-base:publish (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.005 secs.
... so on for other subprojects
```

There is no output at the Nexus repository. How can I fix this?

UPDATE: if I use configuration from chapter 51 of the User Guide, replacing `ivy` by `maven`:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "admin"
                password "admin123"
            }
            url "http://127.0.0.1:9081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

then upload works, but it uploads jars and ivy.xml, without POMs. With config from Chapter 52:

```
configurations {
    deployerJars
}

dependencies {
    deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}

uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.deployerJars
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://127.0.0.1:9081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/") {
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
aromanov@ws:~/etc/apache-s4-0.6.0$ gradle -i upload
Starting Build
Starting file lock listener thread.
...
Publishing configuration: configuration ':s4-base:deployerJars'
Publishing to repository 'mavenDeployer'
[ant:null] Error reading settings file '/tmp/gradle_empty_settings2934509160228124339.xml' - ignoring. Error was: /tmp/gradle_empty_settings2934509160228124339.xml (No such file or directory)
:s4-base:uploadArchives (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.113 secs.
...
```

The [complete build script](https://gist.github.com/alexeyr/7544845).

Comment: Did you declare any publications, as explained in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)? Also note that the new & incubating `maven-publish` plugin has known limitations. For the time being, it's generally safer to use the existing `maven` plugin.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I've tried to use the `maven` plugin, but didn't succeed. See the update.

Comment: If it uploads `ivy.xml`, then something is likely wrong with your build script (but based on the information provided I can't say what). The last snippet fails because a configuration has to be declared before it's being used (i.e. `configurations` has to come before `dependencies`).

Comment: Yes. I've fixed that part, along with `uploadArchives` config. Still no success, but there is at least some progress.

Comment: To help further, I'd need to see all configuration related to publishing in one piece. Not sure what the settings file error means, and whether it's really an error, rather than just some info message.

Comment: I've added the complete build script in a gist. I think the only part directly related to publishing which wasn't there before is that all of this is in `subprojects` after `apply plugin: 'maven'`.

Comment: Some more hints: 1. I wouldn't apply both the `maven` and the `maven-publish` plugin. 2. `uploadArchives.configuration` determines what to upload. Instead, what you want is `uploadArchives.repositories.mavenDeployer.configuration = configurations.deployerJars`. Did we get that wrong in the docs somewhere?

Answer (score 11):

If no any action found, it will mark as **up to date** .
I am using gradle 2.4 and this is working like a charm

```
publishing {
  publications {
      mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
          from components.java
      }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      credentials {
        username 'admin'
        password 'password'
      }
      url "http://baseUrl/artifactory/libs-release-local"
    }
  }
}
```

you need to provide publish repositories and publications.

Comment: I was having same issue until I added a local repository ~/.m2/repository as follows:

        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'file://' + System.getProperty('user.home') + '/.m2/repository/'
            }
        }

Comment: In my case, I got the same message "publish UP-TO-DATE" and the problem solved adding publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You should include the publications block. Something that work for me is to add there all the information as groupId, version, etc.

```
publishing {
   publications {
      myPublication(MavenPublication) {
          ...
          groupId groupBuildId
          artifactId artifactBuildName
          version versionBuild
      }
     ...
  }
```