I cannot find local .jar files in .m2 directory
I want to make a local repository using publishToMavenLocal but after I using this command (even though with built-in button in IntelliJ IDEA IDE), I still cannot find the final directory (test): ".m2/com/test"
This is my build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

What I have checked?

I have built the project.
Double check the directory name.
after adding kts("maven-publish"), I loaded Gradle changes.
Using terminal to run "publishToMavenLocal" and also IDE built-in button
I have checked if the local Maven repository is changed or not, so it is the default one: (User/.m2/)

The messages after running "publishToMavenLocal":

2:47:56 PM: Executing 'publishToMavenLocal'...


Task :publishToMavenLocal UP-TO-DATE


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s


2:47:58 PM: Execution finished 'publishToMavenLocal'.

Do you have any suggestions?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577614/gradles-publishtomavenlocal-task-is-not-executed-correctly

@k314159 thank you, unfortunately not.

You should write your own answer. (That's perfectly acceptable and is in fact a StackOverflow recommended practice.)

The problem was due to the lack of below 'publishing' section and kotlin id("java-library") plugin in the project build.gradle.kts file.

After adding the mentioned lines of code, another build command will be added to your gradle tab, which is called "publishLibraryNamePublicationToMavenLocal":
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    id("java-library")
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "com.test"
version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("[LIBRARY_NAME]") {
            from(components["kotlin"])
        }
    }
}

I have used this link from Gradle documentation to find my answer.
